Does there exist a version of the Slater-Condon rules for a sum of Slater determinants?
The Slater-Condon rules are useful in working out the non-zero single and double electron matrix elements.
For example if $\vert \Psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \vert \phi_{1s}^{\alpha}(1) \phi_{2s}^{\alpha}(2) \vert$ the Slater determinant for the excited state of Helium then the Slater-Condon rules can be used to find the energy of this state represented by the single Slater determinant.
However, if I take the following sum of two Slater determinants $\vert \Psi \rangle = \vert \phi_{1s}^{\alpha}(1) \phi_{2s}^{\beta}(2) \vert + \vert \phi_{1s}^{\beta}(1) \phi_{2s}^{\alpha}(2) \vert$ is there a way to use the Slater-Condon rules?
Generally $det(A) + det(B) \neq det(A+B)$ so I don't see a way to combine the sum into a single determinant.
